# Prolog's built-in reverse function acting odd

Tags: prolog

Given the following code:

```
fun(a, [b]).
fun(b, [c]).
fun(c, [d]).
fun(d, [e]).
fun(e, []).

xyz(X, Y):-
    fun(X,Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A,Z), xyz(A,B)), L),
    flatten(L,F), sort(F,J), reverse(J,Y); Y = [].
```

With the query `xyz(a,X)` I get the expected output `X = [e,d,c,b].`.

What could possibly be throwing this off? Does this have to do with the sort function? If so, according to the documents in the links below, alpha or numeric order of precedence could be throwing this off, but it still doesn't explain by `cs40` is going before `cs30`. I am having a hard time finding a correlation. How can I fix this issue?

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare

By the way, the fun function could have multi-element lists such as fun(a, [b,c], where `a` has multiple dependencies `b` and `c`. This aspect shouldn't matter too much regarding the current issue that I have, but just getting this fact out there.

---

### **UPDATE**

Thanks to @lurker, I've made some great progress.

Given the following code:

```
final_xyz(X, Y):- xyz(X, R), reverse(R, Y).
xyz(X, Y) :-
    fun(X,Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A,Z), xyz(A,B)), L),
    flatten(L,Y); Y = [].
```

In an attempt to fix this, I updated the code to:

```
xyz-final(X,Y):-
  fun(X,Z),
  Z\=0,
  ( length(Z,1) -> xyz(X,J), reverse(J,Y)
  ;
      xyz2(X,B), sort(B,C), reverse(C,Y)
  ).

xyz(K, [X|Y]):- fun(K, [X]), !, xyz(X, Y).
xyz(_, []).

xyz2(X, Y) :-
    fun(X,Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A,Z), xyz2(A,B)), L),
    flatten(L,Y); Y = [].
```

Very clumsy approach, but this seems to work for me now. I'll work on making it more efficient.

Comment: *But it should clearly give me...* Um, no. ;) Remember, `sort`... well, it sorts. So if your initial list is `[cs110, cs40, cs30, m16a]` then it will sort to `[cs110, cs30, cs40, m16a]` because that's in ASCII collating sequence order. (If you sorted them as strings with, for example, `sort` at a Linux prompt, you'd get the same results.) Then when you reverse, you get, `[m16a, cs40, cs30, cs110]` which is expected.

Comment: @lurker hmm ok yeah that does make sense.. here's another strange occurrence.. If I get rid of both of the sort and reverse function, I get `X = [cs110, cs40, cs30, m16a].` Which is correct, but reversed. So, when I include reverse and not sort, I get `X = [cs40, 16a, cs30, cs110].` It shouldn't be throwing it off this time because there's not even a sort function in the implementation. How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: There's more going on there than a reverse if you're going from `X = [cs110, cs40, cs30, m16a]` to `X = [cs40, 16a, cs30, cs110]`. You might need to trace your predicate (enter `trace` then run it again) to see what it's doing. But I can guarantee you: `reverse/2` works just fine. Try typing, `X = [cs110, cs40, cs30, m16a], reverse(X, Y).` at a Prolog prompt and see what it does.

Comment: You are still completely ignoring the rather clean `library(ugraphs)` solution (clean in the sense that it is a library that gives you for free what you are trying to hack on your own). How is this approach better?

Comment: @Boris With all due respect, while your graph approach was much more intuitive and clean, it leads me to the same issue I am currently having. And, that is that the elements aren't in the right order. I believe that that specific graph approach automatically does 'sort' and I'm pretty sure that I should stay away from 'sort'.

Comment: I get your point. Just trying to help. Consider that "flattening" what is in essence a graph to a list is by definition a lossy transformation (and as I think I said before, a "code smell"). Insisting that the list ends up in a particular order, and relying on that order, is always going to be more difficult to get right. Have you made sure that a flat list is the best data structure for your particular use case?

Comment: It hasn't been stated what the requirements on output order are. I think it would be a good exercise for you to attempt to fix the predicate to do what you need. If you analyze it, you can figure it out. This would be a much more effective way to learn Prolog rather than continually asking another question on each detailed issue that you encounter, incorporating other peoples' responses into your evolving solution, and then reporting in an SO question what's not working with what you've incorporated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are wanting to reverse the final result, but your reverse is being done in each recursive call to `xyz/2`. If you do a `trace` on your `xyz(cs140a, X)` call, you'll see it's being called a few times on different recursions.

If you want it once at the end, then you can write it this way:

```
final_xyz(X, Y) :-
    xyz(X, R),
    reverse(R, Y).
xyz(X, Y) :-
    fun(X,Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A,Z), xyz(A,B)), L),
    flatten(L,Y); Y = [].
```

And then calling `final_xyz(cs140a, X)` yields, `X = [m16a,cs30,cs40,cs110]`.

---

Here's an alternative approach to your `xyz` predicate which avoids the `findall` and the `flatten`. This version should avoid cyclical paths and doesn't show duplicates:

```
xyz(X, Y) :-
    fun(X, L),
    xyz(L, [], R),
    reverse(R, Y).

xyz([H|T], A, R) :-
    (   memberchk(H, A)
    ->  xyz(T, A, R)
    ;   fun(H, L)
    ->  xyz(L, [H|A], R1),
        xyz(T, R1, R)
    ;   xyz(T, [H|A], R)
    ).
xyz([], A, A).
```

Comment: that seems intuitive and it works for this scenario, but as I mentioned in the OP, the lists of dependencies could contain multiple elements. In the case of multiple dependencies, for example I am getting `xyz(cs150,X).` which outputs `X = [m16a, cs30, cs40, cs110, m16a, cs30, cs40, cs110, m16a|...].` The sort function from before prevented from redundant duplicate solutions, but since there's no more sort function, this is what's happening. If I include the sort function back in either function, I get the results as I originally was, as expected. How to delete w/ these duplicates?

Comment: @am3decoy can you describe the order you require?

Comment: I will update the original post and try to be more clear, thank you.

Comment: @am3dexoy cool. Meanwhile let me know if my updated answer helps.

Comment: @am3decoy more examples would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @am3decoy I updated my solution that doesn't use `findall` or `flatten`.

Comment: @am3decoy I'm very glad you worked it out. I still wanted to remove the shortcomings of my solution.